# Browserify plugins in Brunch. Can I use them?

Tags: javascript, plugins, browserify, brunch

Can I use Browserify plugins in [Brunch](http://brunch.io)? And if I can, then how? (For example, [Moonify](https://github.com/kbrsh/moonify).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, brunch is a completely different build tool.